# Why do color of things fade and where it goes?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, everyday-life

Suddenly this question comes to mind when i saw a sticky-label faded, when compared to comparatively new one. So question here is does it simply fades away like physical particles or is there anything complex associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

Light causes the dye and/or pigment molecules to degrade with time, and thereby causes the colors of objects with dye or pigment in them to fade.

Ultraviolet light is worst in this regard, which is why colors that do not fade much indoors can nonetheless fade rapidly outdoors where there's a lot more UV present.

Typically, it is harder to make yellow dyes that are fade-resistant, which is why photos and images printed with (cyan/magenta/yellow) dyes will lose the yellow first and the hue of the composite colors will shift.